# CSS Media Queries based on PHP variable

Tags: php, html, css, session, media-queries

I have a multi-lingual website where all the text for the site is being loaded in based on a PHP session variable for each language. My problem here is that when the text is loaded in German, the menu bar on the top of my page becomes too long for it's container and some menu items drop below. This would be okay but the menu items that get dropped down are blocking sub menus from being selected.

Is there a way to use css media queries to reduce font size of my menu when a certain variable is selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such media query but what you can do:

1. check if language in session is German
2. If no, do nothing more than you do at the moment
3. If yes, load one extra CSS file or extra rule where you have defined font-size for example this way:

> ```
> nav ul li {
>   font-size: 10px;
>   font-size: 0.8rem;
> }
> ```

This will change nothing for other language and for German language you can define custom CSS (`font-size` or of course anything else)

Answer (score 4):

The best method is to add a CSS class to the body based on the language e.g `<body class="language-german">` and then write CSS rules based on that

```
body.lang-german nav {font-size: 12px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your CSS file a PHP file. Yes you can do that, it's not magic.

suppose you have a CSS file called `style.css`: rename it `style.css.php` (`.css` is optional)

```
<?php
$lang = $_SESSION['page_lang']; //or however you prefer

if($lang == 'de'){
  echo "german style rules";
} else {
  echo "other style rules";
}
```

of course this is simplified but should make you going.